# React Navigation V5 + Typescript Error: Property 'fullName' does not exist on type 'object'

Tags: typescript, react-native, types, routes, react-navigation

**My Goal:**

I'm trying to add Typescript typings, but having an issue with `route.params.fullName`. When I `console.log(route.params)`, the object `{ fullName: 'John Smith' }` is logged. Why is Typescript having an issue with `fullName`?

The weird part is that the code works and when I navigate to the screen, the header title is updated with `route.params.fullName`.

**Error:**

```
Property 'fullName' does not exist on type 'object'.
```

**Functional Component:**

```
  // React Hooks: React Navigation
  const route = useRoute();

  // React Hooks: Lifecycle Methods
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(route.params);

    // React Navigation: Set Options
    props.navigation.setOptions({
      // ISSUE HERE
      title: route.params.fullName,
    });
  }, [props.navigation, route.params]);
```

Comment: This is react-navigation's fault, they did not type route.params instead gave it an `object` type, which literally forces you to do your own type assertions.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using React Navigation V5, as it says in the documentation, you should first define your route stack params list:

```
export type RootStackParamList = {
  Home: undefined;
  SomeRouteName: { fullName: string };
  ...
};
```

Then while creating your stack navigator, you should use your param list type definition:

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();
```

Finally in your screen component:

```
import { RootStackParamList } from 'YOUR_ROUTE_STACK_PARAM_LIST_PATH';

type SomeScreenComponentRouteProp = RouteProp<RootStackParamList, 'SomeRouteName'>;

interface Props {
  route?: SomeScreenComponentRouteProp;
}

const SomeScreenComponent:  React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
  ...
}
```

This way Typescript will know which params are expected in your route props.

Now you can access your `fullName` parameter via `props.route.params.fullName` without having any errors or warnings.

Answer (score 3):

using

```
let route: any = useRoute();
```

will solve the typescript problem.

**Example:**

Assuming you need to read a parameter named `data` from `route params` that you have passed through:

```
navigation.navigate("productDetails",{data: {title: "New Product Title"})
```

so in your `productDetails` page you can read it like this:

```
import {useRoute} from '@react-navigation/native';

let route: any = useRoute();
let data = route.params?.data ? route.params.data : {};
```

and now there is no typescript problems with your code anymore.

Comment: While your answer may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. You can edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/28227943)

Answer (score 3):

@tsomone answer works but a better and quick solution rather than just using `any` and ignoring everything, is to define `route` type like this:

```
import {RouteProp, useRoute} from '@react-navigation/native';
...
let route: RouteProp<{params: {fullName: string}}, 'params'> = useRoute();
```

You will no longer get that error.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you could

```
import { RootStackParamList } from 'YOUR_ROUTE_STACK_PARAM_LIST_PATH';

type Props =StackScreenProps<RootStackParamList, 'SomeRouteName'>;

const SomeScreenComponent:  React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
  ...
}
```

This way you take prop typing directly